# SVG-PanZoom doesn't work if container gets hidden

Tags: svgpanzoom

I have a SVG-Pan-Zoom instance embedded in an Tabbing-Component. When the active tab changes, the previous one gets hidden with `display: none`. After switching back to the first tab (which gets displayed again with `display: block`) the svgPanZoom instance is in an unusable state. I dont't really get what is going on.

I was able to reproduce this behaviour only in Google Chrome.

I've created an example to test this: http://svgpan-example.bitballoon.com/

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a browser specific implementation. 
When you're setting `display: none` on the `embed` element (or its parent container) the browser most probably unloads the resource. After removing the `display: none` - it looks like the browser is reinitialising/reloading the resource. You can see that based on 2 facts:

- In Network tabs of Developer Tools you can see that the resource is loaded again when you show the element
- If you alter an element inside of SVG (in inspector), after hiding and showing - the change is gone.

*svg-pan-zoom* has no control over SVG changes from the external world, so it's not an issue. A solution is to use inline SVG (they worked for me when hiding/showing), or just test all other options (object and img tags). But an inline SVG is always the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

An object with display: hidden is removed from the flow of the DOM and so in some browsers will not have any dimensional data (width, height) at this time.  My solution may be a bit hokey but...  I needed an SVG in a bootstrap modal.  So I put the svg element in the bottom of the body outside the modal, set the visibility: hidden.  Then initialized svgPanZoom on it.  Then moved it (using jQuery) into the hidden modal.  This solved the problem for me.

```
    <div id="svgContainer" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; 
      border:1px solid black; padding:5px; overflow:hidden; 
      visibility: hidden"><svg>...</svg></div>
```